# Search and yank in visual line mode with execute normal

Tags: search, visual-mode, normal-mode

I have this in a buffer:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

with the cursor on the first line. I do `:execute 'normal! jV/ddd\<CR>y'` which I expect should result in the middle three lines yanked. But what actually happens is it just ends up in visual mode on the second line with nothing yanked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your command doesn't work is `<cr>` is not automatically expanded.  Instead you need to use double quotes and a backslash.

```
execute "normal! jV/ddd\<CR>y"
```

Actually you don't really need to bother with visual mode here; what you want can be done using

```
2,/ddd/y
```

This means from second line, up till and including search for `ddd`, yank.